# JMeter behavior when log file can't be written to

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

During test execution, we run out of space and can't write to log file any more. JMeter triggered via jmeter-maven-plugin hangs. I'd like JMeter to fail and exit, rather than keep hanging. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

- Make sure that you have disabled unnecessary listeners during
  execution and other samplers
- Try to use request defaults in your test plan.
- Also, try to execute script using command line.

How many threads you are injecting?

=============================================

Open JMeter.bat in editor and edit following values:

set HEAP=-server -Xms768m -Xmx768m -Xss128k

set NEW=-XX:NewSize=1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m

Comment: This will increase the available memory size (If there is any), however if the new memory size will not be enough, JMeter will be hanging and the issue will remain. That's not a solid solution.